# Why sigma algebra and not other systems of sets?

Tags: measure-theory

I got a short question. Why we are considering sigma-algebras and not other systems of sets in measure-theory? Why not dynkin-system for example?

Comment: Good question. Maybe by comparing the definition of a sigma algebra with the axioms for a probability measure might give some insite.

Comment: A precisation: with "why not dynkin-system?" do you mean "Why don't we just require it to be a Dynkin system?" or "Why don't we cross out the request of it being a Dynkin system?" ?

Answer (score 4):

The Dynkin-system is poor for the purpose of measure theory. In measure theory (probability theory) calculating the measure of a sets over which a sequence of functions converges is important.

Let, for instance, $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions. Then te set

$$\{x: \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)\}$$ cannot be expressed in general in a Dynkin system.

Why not? Because

$$\{x: \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{m=N}^{\infty}\{x:|f_m(x)-f(x)|\le\frac{1}{n}\}.$$

Such a set cannot be expressed in a Dynkin system unless it contains at least the finite intersections of its sets.

**Saying that a Dynkin system is too special deserves a down vote!**

Comment: It would be nice if whoever gave this a down vote could give some constructive criticism.

Comment: I am an absolute follower of the rules. A down vote is a down vote. I deserve it by definition.

Comment: @Wintermute, I think that my edited version is getting better received.

Answer (score 3):

For instance, you want "measurable functions" to be a ring, hence you want $1_A\cdot1_B=1_{A\cap B}$ to be "measurable" if $A,B$ are "measurable". But this means that you want "measurable sets" to be closed under finite intersection.

But a [Dynkin system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system) closed under finite intersection is a $\sigma$-algebra.

**Added**

The fact is that you first *want* to define what "being measurable set" means, and then you *want* to say that a function $\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is "measurable" if the counterimage of open sets is "measurable". Which *implies* that a characteristic function $1_A$ is "measurable" if and only if $A$ is "measurable". Now the point is that the more you want (both algebraically and analytically) on the set of "measurable function", the more you need on the "measurable sets".

There exists, anyways, a theory of [non-$\sigma$-algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets), corresponding to finitely additive measures, which (I've been told) have some use in number theory.

Comment: Is the theory of non-sigma algebras, i.e. just algebras, corresponding to finitely additive measures, the same thing as Boolean algebras? If so, then they also have numerous applications in computer science (they might no longer be fashionable in mathematical logic circles though, I have no idea, definitely still important in computer science though)